# Using filter inside Ember.RSVP.hash fails to retrieve data in qunit test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit

I have a qunit test on a route that uses TWO models and use `Ember.RSVP.hash` to accomplish this. Things work as expected but as soon as I add a `filter` to `Ember.RSVP.hash` it stops retrieving data in qunit. Outside of qunit it still works so I believe it's an issue with `filter`, `Ember.RSVP.hash` and `qunit`.

Here's my test:

```
module('Ember.js Library', {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test('foo', function() {
  visit('/books');
  andThen(function() {
    equal(currentRouteName(), 'books.index');
  });
});
```

Here's the working route that does not use `filter`:

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var id = 1;

    // note this does not filter "books" properly
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      books: this.store.find('books'),
      library: this.store.find('library', id)
    });
  }
});
```

Here's the version that uses `filter` and does not work:

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var id = 1;

    // note: filters "books" properly but doesn't work in qunit
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      books: this.store.filter('books', function(record) {
        return record.get('libraryId') === id;
      }),
      library: this.store.find('library', id)
    });
  }
});
```

The end result is that in the working version, `books` is present as expected. In the second version, `books` ends up being empty. In both versions the `library` is always present so I believe `filter` is the problem.

How can I use `filter` and get things to work with qunit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`store.filter` doesn't actually load the records, it will only return records that are already in the store. What you probably want to do is something like...

```
App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var id = 1;

    // note: filters "books" properly but doesn't work in qunit
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      books: this.store.find('books').then(function(books){
        return books.filterBy('libraryId', id)
      }),
      library: this.store.find('library', id)
    });
  }
});
```

(disclaimer: the code above is untested but thats the idea)

Comment: I'm going to try this out. But my code works when I run it locally, just not in qunit.

Comment: is it possible that locally the store is getting preloaded by a different call to `this.store.find('books')`?

Comment: You were right, it was preloaded in application route. Not sure why that doesn't work in qunit...guess it's time for another SO question.

Comment: Question about why the model hook isn't firing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351221/application-routes-model-hook-not-triggering-in-qunit-integration-test