# application route's model hook not triggering in qunit integration test

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I have a route that looks like this:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log("caching books");
    this.store.find('books');
  }
});
```

When I run it locally I see the "caching books" message in the console. But when I run it in qunit the message never shows up.

**Why does the application route's model hook not fire in qunit?**

Here's my qunit integration test:

```
module('Ember.js Library', {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test('root url redirects to leads list', function() {
  visit('/');
  andThen(function() {
    // assert
  });
});
```

Comment: Im not sure but i have a guess : actually '/' references your index route not your application route. however when visiting your route through your browser to go to index you pass by application however in testing may be not ...

Comment: @MrVinz thanks for the guess but I see this in my logs `Transition #0: application: calling beforeModel hook` so it looks like the model hook is firing. Weird.